# Two-state button that mimics a checkbox in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to make a button on an MFC tool bar that can be pressed and retain it's state until pressed again (like a check box) but I don't want a tick box. I'd ideally like a button that changes between two icons and uses DDV to change the value of a boolean on being pressed. How would I go about this.

As a side question I could really do with a good book on MFC. I've got Programming Windows with MFC 2nd edition, but was wondering if there was anything that went into a bit more detail?

Comment: I think you could write a customization button inherited from CButton to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` to set the state of the button. e.g. a typical handler will look like this:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyView, CView)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_MY_BUTTON, OnUpdateMyButton)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

...

void CMyView::OnUpdateMyButton(CCmdUI* pCmdUI) 
{
    // TODO: Add your command update UI handler code here

    pCmdUI->SetCheck( isButtonPressed() );
}
```

With regard to good MFC documentation I recommend Professional MFC (Mike Blaszczak) - it's a little old but very good.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of the CToolBar Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69wz6ea1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

To create a check-box button, assign it the style TBBS_CHECKBOX or use a CCmdUI object's SetCheck member function in an ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI handler.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a Radio Button on Dialog box.

Select Radio button & go to button Properties page.

Set Push Like property & set as "True"

Add event handler for the same control & take Boolean variable.

Use API -> "CheckDlgButton(IDC_RADIO1, 1);" for set status as per Boolean variable value.

for more details. visit below link.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/530/A-Better-Bitmap-Button-Class